# My mac reports 4 Vulkan queue families but reference says it has 1

Tags: macos, vulkan, moltenvk

My home computer is a late 2012 Mac Mini, it has a 3rd gen Intel IvyBridge processor (mobile model for some reason only Apple knows).

The "vulkaninfo.app" from the LunarG SDK reports 4 queue families on the integrated GPU, but [public information](http://vulkan.gpuinfo.org/displayreport.php?id=3797#queuefamilies) shows that it should only have 1 one it. What's happening?

```
VkQueueFamilyProperties[0]:
===========================
    queueFlags         = GRAPHICS | COMPUTE | TRANSFER
    queueCount         = 1
    timestampValidBits = 64
    minImageTransferGranularity = (1, 1, 1)
    present support    = true

VkQueueFamilyProperties[1]:
===========================
    queueFlags         = GRAPHICS | COMPUTE | TRANSFER
    queueCount         = 1
    timestampValidBits = 64
    minImageTransferGranularity = (1, 1, 1)
    present support    = true

VkQueueFamilyProperties[2]:
===========================
    queueFlags         = GRAPHICS | COMPUTE | TRANSFER
    queueCount         = 1
    timestampValidBits = 64
    minImageTransferGranularity = (1, 1, 1)
    present support    = true

VkQueueFamilyProperties[3]:
===========================
    queueFlags         = GRAPHICS | COMPUTE | TRANSFER
    queueCount         = 1
    timestampValidBits = 64
    minImageTransferGranularity = (1, 1, 1)
    present support    = true
```

Comment: Maybe the driver implementation changed? Did you check on that?

Comment: @FelixK. I did a bit of checking. SDK ver 1.1.108 reports 4 queue families of 1 queue each, 1.0.69 reports 1 queue family of 16 queues. The latter I suspect to be the old MoltonVK driver errornously reporting the number of compute units, which executes in parallel synchronously, unlike queues which executes asynchronously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In macOS, there's no queue count or queue family count in Metal Devices (as of July 2019), so one could create 1 or any number of queues and get full utilization of the device.

However, as noted in a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/MoltenVK/issues/449), some programs with hardwired assumptions crashes when there's only 1 queue family, so they made MoltenVK report 4 queue families to fix it (see [pull request 450](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/MoltenVK/pull/450)).

Comment: So, to fix other peoples' broken applications, MoltenVK lies?

Comment: @NicolBolas basically yes.

Comment: How do those applications work on Intel implementations, which uniformly expose exactly 1 queue family and exactly 1 queue?